# Is it Possible to Add or Multiply Groups?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, gre-exam

I came across a GRE Mathematics Subject test question that said the following:

"Find the characteristic of the ring $Z_2 + Z_3$."

The explanation of the question starts with the statement that $$Z_2 + Z_3 = \{(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2)\}$$ My question is whether or not $Z_2 + Z_3$ is the proper way to label this set. Every other question I've come across using sets like this uses $Z_2 \times Z_3$. Is $Z_2 + Z_3$ the same thing as $Z_2 \times Z_3$ or is this an error in the text? Furthermore, if $Z_2 + Z_3$ is NOT the proper notation for this set, what would be the mathematical significance of adding these two groups (assuming $Z_n = \{0, 1, 2, \dots, n-1\}$ under addition modulo *n*)? Can groups be added, subtracted?

Also within the same text I came across a similar question regarding invariant subgroups:  If *H* and *K* are both invariant subgroups of *G* (i.e. if $gH=Hg$ and $gK=Kg$ for every *g* in *G*), is *HK* also an invariant subgroup? Again, I'm not totally understanding the mathematical significance of *HK*. Does that mean $H \times K$ or something totally different?

I've found that the book I'm using has a few other errors that have been noted here and on other websites, so I want to be sure I'm thinking about this the proper way. Any answers, links, or recommended reading would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: HK is totally different. It is the set of all products $hk$, where $h$ ranges over $H$ and $k$ ranges over $K$.

Comment: I'd guess $HK$ means $\{hk : h \in H, k \in K\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $H$ and $K$ are *abelian* groups (where the operation is usually written as addition), then it is standard to write $H\oplus K$ instead of $H\times K$.  $H+K$ is... well, it's clear what's meant, but it's strange and non-standard.

If $H$ and $K$ are both subgroups of a third abelian group, then $H+K$ should describe the internal sum $\{h+k\mid h\in H, k\in K\}$, which is only isomorphic to $H\oplus K$ if $H\cap K = \{0\}$.  So this is a practical reason to avoid the notation $H+K$ when referring to the direct sum/direct product of two abelian groups.

For general (possibly non-abelian) groups, we should *never* write $H+K$, because it's bad practice to think of nonabelian operations additively.  For general groups, the notation $HK$ is the same thing, just written multiplicatively: $HK = \{hk \mid h\in H, k\in K\}$.  This is standard, though extra conditions are required for it to actually be a group.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. That makes a great deal more sense. I really appreciate your time and assistance!